# make openmp g++-6.2.0 no such file

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, itk

cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(multithreading)

# Find ITK.
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenMP REQUIRED)
if(OPENMP_FOUND)
message("OPENMP FOUND")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS “${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}”)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS “${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}“)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS “${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}”)
endif()

add_executable(multithreading multithreading.cpp )

target_link_libraries(multithreading ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(multithreading ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES})
```

And then I change default compiler which is AppleClang to gcc-6.2.0, and then cmake
,all openmp flags find, and configure is fine.

cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/gcc-6.2.0 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/g++-6.2.0 ./

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/gcc-6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/gcc-6.2.0 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/g++-6.2.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/gcc-6.2.0/bin/g++-6.2.0 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp  
OPENMP FOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

then next when I do ‘make’ it shows me

```
canning dependencies of target multithreading
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/multithreading.dir/multithreading.cpp.o
g++-6.2.0: error: “: No such file or directory
g++-6.2.0: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
/bin/sh: -fopenmp“: command not found
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/multithreading.dir/multithreading.cpp.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/multithreading.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I do g++ -fopenmp myproject.cpp it will not link ITK Library

```
g++ -fopenmp multithreading.cpp 
multithreading.cpp:4:44: fatal error: itkRescaleIntensityImageFilter.h: No such file or directory
 #include "itkRescaleIntensityImageFilter.h"
                                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I am wondering how can I fix that issue, so use itk and openmp as library at the same time.

Comment: Do not use **language-specific double quotes** (`“`) in CMake scripts. [Similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149743/cmake-set-property-could-not-find-cache-variable/41151401) has been arised recently.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am not carefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using language/locale-specific double quotes. Most programming languages don't support these, including CMake. Use the "normal" double quotes: `"`